# ONSEN UI: Can I use same header or menu and footer for all the html files? If yes HOW?

Tags: onsen-ui

I am developing an app using onsen ui and angular js. Lets say I have 3 html files(physical) not the ons-template one on the same page. How can I make a header of menu that will appear on all the three pages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with `ons-navigator` and `ons-toolbar`. You can add a footer in the same way, although a little css adjustment will be needed.

```js
ons.bootstrap()
```

```css
.back-button-icon{
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 44px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  width: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
.back-button-text{
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 44px;
  height: 44px;
}

ons-toolbar ~ ons-navigator .page__content{
  margin-top: 44px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

<ons-toolbar>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="toolbar-button" ng-show="navi.getPages().length > 1" ng-click="navi.popPage()">
      <i class="ion-ios-arrow-back back-button-icon"></i><span class="back-button-text">Back</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">Title</div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</ons-toolbar>

<ons-navigator var="navi" page="page1.html"></ons-navigator>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="page1.html">
  <ons-page>
    <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px">
    Content of Page1
      <ons-button onclick="navi.pushPage('page2.html')">PushPage</ons-button>
    </div>
  </ons-page>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="page2.html">
  <ons-page>
    <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px">
    Content of Page2
      <ons-button onclick="navi.pushPage('page3.html')">PushPage</ons-button>
    </div>
  </ons-page>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="page3.html">
  <ons-page>
    <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px">
    Content of Page3
    </div>
  </ons-page>
</script>
```